# get specific data from database and print it to a cell

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a simple code for studying vocabulary and want this code to look up the words in `column "A"` using my favorite online dictionary "Cambridge" automatically and then print the definitions to the cells next to the words. I have written the code below so far and it goes to the site and searches the word. The question is what code is needed to get the definitions and print them to the cells?

```
Sub SearchWords()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "www.dictionary.cambridge.org"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("cdo-search-input")
HTMLInput.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value

Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("cdo-search__button")

HTMLButtons(0).Click

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The result appears to be in an element with classname `entry`. I read your column A search words in to an array and loop that to look up each word. The result is written back out to the sheet. I use [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) mostly as a more flexible and faster method for selecting elements.  css selectors, in this instance, are applied via [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) method of `HTMLDocument` (i.e. `ie.Document`)

Proper page loads waits are used throughout.

```
Option Explicit

'entry
Public Sub SearchWords()
    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, lookups(), dataSheet As Worksheet, iRow As Long

    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    lookups = Application.Transpose(dataSheet.Range("A2:A3").Value) '<Read words to lookup into a 2d array and transpose into 1D

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "www.dictionary.cambridge.org"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        For iRow = LBound(lookups) To UBound(lookups)
            .document.getElementById("cdo-search-input").Value = lookups(iRow) 'work off .document to avoid stale elements
            .document.querySelector(".cdo-search__button").Click
            While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend 'wait for page reload
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
            Do
            Loop While .document.querySelectorAll(".entry").Length = 0
            dataSheet.Cells(iRow + 1, 2) = .document.querySelector(".entry").innerText
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks very nice, and I tried it immediately, but when I run this macro I get this error code "Subscript out of range" related to the line "Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")". I'm sure I have missed something, but what?

Comment: Change the sheet name from Sheet1 to the name of the sheet with your values in

Comment: It works, but this time the macro skips some of the words, i mean it pastes the meanings of  some of the words more than once, so some words are still missing, and as i mentioned in the new reply (I couldn't post it as a comment since it was too long) I found the "full definition part" on the page, but this time the classname didn't work.

Comment: Yes, after a couple of changes (but for your advice about using css selectors, it would last forever for me to solve it) I now have an impeccably working macro, which includes every single detail. That was a great help, and many thanks for your swift replies.

Comment: One last question about the same title, I tried to adapt the code for a different page but it didn't work. The site is "sentencedict.com", and I need the part where example sentences are placed(I think its "name" is "all"). I get an error code and the words don't appear in the search bar, so the page isn't loaded. Do I have to start over? Or is there a way to use the previous code for this new web site?

Answer (score 0):

Done! Perfectly working. (Since this post is too long for a comment, I had to post this as an answer) Now I am trying to get some more data from the page(since I need the other explanations and Turkish definitions as well). When I inspect the page, I see that full descriptions are placed in "di $ entry-body__el entry-body__el--smalltop clrd js-share-holder" class. I added "/turkish" to the URL and tried to get the related element using the class name I mentioned instead of ".def-block", but it didn't work. Then I tried a different way using this code:

```
Sub GetMeaningsFromCambridgeDictionary()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Meanings")
    Dim sourceWord As String
    sourceWord = ws.Range("A2").Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim çeviri As String
    Dim ilkSatir As Integer
    ilkSatir = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim URL As String
    Dim countElement As Integer


    Range("B2:B1000").Delete


    IE.Visible = False
    URL = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/turkish/" & sourceWord

    IE.Navigate URL

    Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Do While IE.readyState <> 4
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Loop

    countElement = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("di $ entry-body__el entry-body__el--smalltop clrd js-share-holder").Length
    For i = 0 To countElement - 1
        çeviri = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("di $ entry-body__el entry-body__el--smalltop clrd js-share-holder")(i).innerText
        Range("B" & i + 2).Value = çeviri
        Range("B" & i + 2).Rows.AutoFit
    Next i
    Columns(2).AutoFit
    IE.Quit
    MsgBox "All meanings have been copied."

End Sub
```

This code is also working, and I see all the definitions in detail, but this time the problem is only the first word is done. What should I do to do the same thing for the other words?